# how to change the legends of highcharts to custom name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am new to highcharts and I want to change the text of the legends of the charts with the text that i have in an array. I have an array of "name" and i want it to be the text of the legends. Is there any way to solve my problem?

The jsfiddle link is given in the comment below. Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abgjtc73/2/ Here is the jsfiddle

Comment: Just use a loop to create an new array of data. http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/abgjtc73/7/

Comment: You can also use [labelFormatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter) and return custom name.

Answer (score 0):

To change series name displayed in legend, but not name of a series, then you could use [labelFormatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter) (as Sebastian suggested). If series are indexed the same as your `name` array then you could access series _i property and use it to get proper name from `name` array.

```
var name = ["a","b","c","d"];
...
        legend: {
            labelFormatter: function () {
                return name[this._i];
            }
...
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3ks9cxvn/1/